# Probability: Calculating simple probability

Tags: probability

Here is my question:

A number is chosen at random from the integers $1$ to $10$. Find the probability that the number is 
a.) Prime

b.) a multiple of $2$

c.) either prime $\textbf{or} $ a multiple of $2$.

My view:

$s=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$$\\$
$n(s)=10\\
\mathrm{Prime \;numbers} \{2, 3, 5, 7, \} 
$

a.) Pr(Prime) = $\frac{4}{10} $

b.) multiple of 2 $\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}\\$

Pr(multiple of 2)=$\frac{5}{10}$

c.) Either prime or multiple of two

First view: Pr(prime) $\frac{4}{10}$ +Pr(multiple of 2) $\frac{5}{10}=\frac{9}{10}$

Second view: I tried listing out all the numbers that fall in category, $\textbf{prime or even} $ which are $\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10\}$

Going by this counting I have $\frac{8}{10}\;$ as the probability.

Why the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a Venn diagram, you may be able to spot that $$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$

so you should get $$\frac4{10}+\frac5{10}-\frac1{10}=\frac8{10}$$ since there is $1$ even prime number

Comment: Oh!! I have counted $2$ twice. Thanks